# SQL - How to select ID having multiple rows with values from different lists

Tags: sql

I have data broken up by ID with varying 'codes'; an example would be:

```
ID    Code_Value
1     100
1     200
1     300
1     600
1     700
2     300
2     600 
2     700
3     400
3     600
3     800
etc.
```

My goal is to identify all ID groups having a Code_Value contained within two different lists; so, if I were to look for ID's having a code within ('100','300','500') AND a code within ('600','700','800'), it would return the ID values of 1 and 2 from the example data above.

I've found examples combining these lists into one overarching list and identifying which IDs have a certain number of hits within that overarching list (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/95674/get-id-which-has-two-rows-with-different-values-for-one-column), but this is no good for me because I need the ID to contain values from each individual list set.

An example attempt I have made is the following:

```
select id from my_table
where code_value in (<list_1>)
and code_value in (<list_2>)
group by id;
```

The result is that I receive all ID's having individual code_value in each list, rather than having ANY code_value across the entire ID within each list.

Any help on this would be very much appreciated,
UncleSam

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `having` clause:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having sum(case when code_value in (<list_1>) then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when code_value in (<list_2>) then 1 else 0 end) > 0 ;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause counts the number of values for each list.  The `> 0` simply says there is at least one.

Comment: Hi, this didn't seem to work for me. I keep getting a syntax error employing your solution; are you sure that code structure as written works?

Comment: My error is:  [Code: 1064, SQL State: 42000]  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group by id
having (sum(case when code_value in ('1','2',' at line 4

Comment: Ok I think I solved my own problem: It is the extraneous where statement that causes errors in your code example above. Without it the code runs smoothly. Thanks for your help anyway, though! The having suggestion helped a lot